# What are these values bootstrap adds in :root?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I was source inspecting my bootstrap site and see the following css:

```
:root {
    --blue: #007bff;
    --indigo: #6610f2;
    --purple: #6f42c1;
    --pink: #e83e8c;
    --red: #dc3545;
    --orange: #fd7e14;
    --yellow: #ffc107;
    --green: #28a745;
    --teal: #20c997;
    --cyan: #17a2b8;
    --white: #fff;
    --gray: #6c757d;
    --gray-dark: #343a40;
    --primary: #007bff;
    --secondary: #6c757d;
    --success: #28a745;
    --info: #17a2b8;
    --warning: #ffc107;
    --danger: #dc3545;
    --light: #f8f9fa;
    --dark: #343a40;
    --breakpoint-xs: 0;
    --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
    --breakpoint-md: 768px;
    --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
    --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
}
```

What are these things? I understand that they are not CSS properties but what is `--blue`?

Comment: Read about [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)

Comment: These are variables. So for example you can use --blue in several cases but if you need to change the --blue then you only need to do that on one place.